# How can I reload the page when I changed one of my required modules in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, node-modules

For example, I have "A" folder in my root directory and I am requiring this "A" from another folder, let say "B". Entering "npm install" command in "B". "Folder A" is coming to B's node_modules,as expected. I want also reload my webpack,when ı changed "A" folder files under the root, not B's node_modules's "A".
        I think I need some auto install plugin or something.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) helps you. If you run your app using nodemon then any changes in the project will restart the node application.

Comment: I need to do that with web pack. Thanks for reply.